# Easy ArrayList Model Object

Tags: java, arraylist

This works when sending `["John", "Jane"]`

```
@PostMapping("/v1/newapplications")
public void createvisitor(@RequestBody ArrayList<application> newapplications) {}
```

```
public class application {
  private String firstname;
  public application(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
  }
}
```

But, I want to send `[{"firstname":"John"},{"firstname": "Jane"}]`.

I am guessing I need to create an object model similar to the following that's within the Array, but how do I adjust the `application` model to account for this?

```
public class name {
  private String firstname;
  public name(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
  }
}
```

Comment: I run your code it works well

Comment: @TongChen My question is not about if any code runs well.

Comment: You want send `["John", "Jane"]` not works well?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following may work, but this depends on how exactly the values need to be stored. Can the colon be a String? I'm guessing these are key/value pairs for a DB so I'm not sure, but if so:

```
public class name {
  private String keyValue = "firstName";
  private String firstname;
  private String keyValuePair;

  public name(String firstname) {
    this.keyValuePair = keyValue + ":" + firstName;
  }
}
```

Again this creates one long String, so it entirely depends on how you plan on using it.

Comment: I am going to use a JPA repository connected to MySQL. The goal will be to have two columns one with a primary key and a second column with the entire ArrayList<application>, which is essentially an array with a bunch of objects. The objects are filled with a bunch of key value pairs that are mapped as Map<String, Object>. - Not sure if that makes sense.